# WPF: TextBlock with Wrapped text should inherit width

Tags: wpf, xaml, width

I have the following XAML:

```
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Border Name="B1" Width="Auto">
                        <DataGrid />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Name="B2" Width="Auto">
                        <DataGrid />
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
                <Border Name="B3" Width="Auto">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"
                               Text="{Binding}"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
```

Basically, borders B1 and B2 are side by side on top, and B3 is below them.  B1 and B2 change their widths dynamically according to stuff going on in their contents.  I want the width of B3 to be the sum of the widths of B1 and B2, with word wrapping of the potentially long text in the TextBlock.

The XAML above results in the text in the TextBlock not to wrap, which results in B3 being much wider then B1+B2.

I want B3.width to inherit from the main StackPanel's width, which will be set by B1.width+B2.width, and I would like to do it without code behind if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stk">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="stk1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Border Name="B1"
                Width="Auto">
            <ListBox Width="200" Height="200"></ListBox>
        </Border >
        <Border Name="B2"
                Width="Auto">
            <ListBox Width="200"></ListBox>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    <Border Name="B3"
            Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=stk1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                   Text="testddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" />
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```